# OnPointerDown doesn't work with Canvas component

Tags: unity-game-engine, events, unity-ui

I am using canvas component for ovveride sorting, and when i use a object with canvas component, OnPointerDown doesn't detect clicks but when i delete, it  can detect cliks, how can i use canvas and OnPointerDown at same object

[Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U1FK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just add Graphic Raycaster to object which has canvas component